# Help me understand std::erase

Tags: c++, stl

In the book 'C++ In A Nutshell', there is the following example code

```
std::vector<int> data
...
std::erase(std::remove(data.begin(), data.end(), 42),
  data.end());
```

I thought that 'erase' was a member function, so shouldn't that be 'data.erase' rather than 'std::erase'?
Is there some way the c++ compiler can tell what member you wanted to call a member function on, or did the book omit any documentation of an erase template function, or is the example wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`erase` is a member function. The sample provided is incorrect.

Answer (score 7):

There is no `std::erase`. `std::map::erase`, `std::list::erase` exists. But no `std::erase` exists.

Look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809227/how-to-get-the-first-n-elements-of-a-stdmap/1809336#1809336) about phantom std::erase.

Comment: To be specific, all sequence and associative containers provide member `erase()`  (it's part of their requirements), as well as `std::basic_string`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, erase is a member function, so it should be `data.erase()` instead of `std::erase()`.

Answer (score 3):

You observation is correct. 'Erase' should be a member function. Only a member function on a container can change the memory size of that container.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry their is no generic erase, just double checked

Comment: There's no generic algorithm `erase`.

Comment: ... not even in `<algorithm>` (go ahead, try it).

Comment: yes i was incorrect saying that there was a generic erase algorithm(i remembered wrong). but there is a algorithm header in the standard library. Which includes alot of generic algorithms(find, includes, etc.), which works with the various stl containers.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: algorithms in STL operate on iterators, and through that they can change the contents of a container, but they cannot change the container itself. Erase is a method that modifies the size of the container and as such cannot be implemented in terms of iterators, but needs access to the container itself.

Comment: @dribeas: but note that there are `insert_iterator`s, which can change the size of the container. There are no matching `delete_iterator`s, but there's no real reason there couldn't be.

Comment: Insert iterators are categorized as output iterators, which is an existing and well-defined category. They don't add anything to the contract of that category. What would "delete iterators" be categorized as?

Answer (score 0):

There is an algorithm called std::remove. And calling erase on the data structure.  remove moves all the elements to be erased to the end of the iterator range and returns the first element to be removed.  Returns end() if the element could not be found.

So then you call erase on range starting with the return value of std::remove and the end of the data structure.

See: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/remove.html

Note that remove won't work with ordered datastructures, as the elements can't be rearranged.

remove is linear, and so would be removing a vector from up to the end.  As it wouldn't need to bubble up the elements after the elements to be removed.

```
std::vector<int> data
...
data.erase(std::remove(data.begin(), data.end(), 42), data.end())
```

compared to something like this which is O(N**2)

```
std::vector<int> data
...
for ( i = data.begin(), i != data.end(); ++i ) {
  if ( *i == 42 ) data.erase( i ) ;
}
```

Comment: Read the question again.  It uses std::remove.  You don't have to say "what looks what they wanted", because that's what they used.