# Can't find toupper and erase

Tags: c++

So, I've been doing Reddit's [daily programmer #140](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/1q6pq5/11413_challenge_140_easy_variable_notation/) and can't use std::toupper and std::erase.

Includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
```

Part with toupper and erase (used to transform words to 'CamelCase'):

```
std::string tekst;
std::cin >> tekst;    

tekst[0] = std::touppper(tekst[0]);
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < tekst.size(); i++){
    if(tekst[i] == 32){
        std::erase(tekst[i], 1);
        tekst[i] = std::toupper(tekst[i]);
    }
}
```

And compiler shows errors:

```
error: 'touppper' is not a member of 'std'
error: 'erase' is not a member of 'std'
```

What can cause it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Neither of those are standard functions...

Comment: @chris [Oh rly?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper)

Comment: You don't specify compiler but in MSVC you'd need to `#include <locale>`

Comment: @H2CO3: The link you posted was to `toupper` (with two `p`s), while chris commented on the one in the question here, which is `touppper` (3 `p`s). The poster's version is in fact not part of the `std` namespace.

Comment: [No erase in namespace std](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=erase).

Comment: There is an `erase` member function in `string`: should be `tekst.erase(i, 1)`

Comment: @H2CO3: Sorry. Forgot the :D in my last comment. It was meant as a joke. The error the poster quoted does in fact have three `p`s in it, though.

Comment: @KenWhite Now I feel bad. Upvoted that. I'm somehow not getting jokes today. :D Sorry...

Comment: @H2CO3: No harm, no foul. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::touppper` does not exist, as it is spelled with two `p`'s, not with three :). `std::erase` is not a standard function, check this: [Help me understand std::erase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821703/help-me-understand-stderase)

Comment: Oh God, thank you for sparing your time for such noob as me :)

Comment: @user2974775 this mistake could happen to anyone, don't judge yourself :)

Answer (score 4):

Not

```
std::touppper
```

but

```
std::toupper
```

You need to pass a locale to the function, see for example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/toupper/

Answer (score 0):

You probaly want to use `std::toupper()` as the basis of your implementation. Note, however, that `std::toupper()` takes its argument as `int` and requires that the argument is a positive value of `EOF`. Passing negative values to the one argument version of `std::toupper()` will result in undefined behavior. On platforms where `char` is signed you will easily get negative values, e.g., when using ISO-Latin-1 encoding with my second name. The canonical approach is to use `std::toupper()` with the `char` convert to an `unsigned char`:

```
tekstr[0] = std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(tekstr[0]));
```

With respect to `erase()` you are probably looking for `std::string::erase()`:

```
tekstr.erase(i);
```

Note that if the string ends in a space, you don't want to access the character at index `i` after blowing the last space away!